# How can I delete everything and leave only this in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, script, regex

I'm trying to get rid of everything after a column in Notepad++. Column mode is not an option. Is it possible?

What I have

```
1111111111,,,+96,,,Aadil,Al Jadeedi,
2222222222,,rock@email.com,+96,,,
```

What I need

```
1111111111,+96
2222222222,+96
```

Comment: Can you post your attempts at doing this? What have you done so far to achieve this goal? This site is not a free scripting service. The community here helps those who help themselves. So if you have attempted to do something to achieve this goal, please post your code/script/formula and the community can attempt to help you. As it stands this question reads as a free scripting request and will most likely be closed as a result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(.*?,)(?:.*?,){2}(.*?),.*$`
- Replace with: `$1$2`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    (           # group 1
        .*?         # 0 or more any character, not greedy
        ,           # comma
    )           # end group 1
    (?:         # non capture group
        .*?         # 0 or more any character, not greedy
        ,           # comma
    ){2}        # end group, must appear twice
    (           # group 2
        .*?         # 0 or more any character, not greedy
    )           # end group 2
    ,           # comma
    .*          # 0 or more any character
$
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: work , thanks alot

Comment: @sparta4545: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @Toto By posting an answer to this question that was basically a scripting request, the original poster decided to [post _another_ question as an “answer” here](https://superuser.com/a/1752178/167207). This is _exactly_ why you should not answer questions that show little to no effort.

Comment: @Giacomo1968: You're right but it seems OP doesn't know how regex works. I've given them a detailled answer that should help them to understand.